# The eclipse keyboard shortcuts of collapsing&expanding editor don't work

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, editor, shortcut, fold

I know the default  keyboard shortcuts  of folding&expanding editor and how to rebind them.

But whatever the shortcut I've set didn't take effect.

I rebound the folding keyboard shortcut with "Ctrl + -" , "Ctrl + i" , even " - ".

But when I press the keys nothing happened.

If I should set something else?

Comment: Which editor are you using? This works fine in the Java editor for me.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah~ , I solved it..

Maybe this problem only happened to me, anyhow Share to everyone~:

The collapse defauty keyboard shortcut is "Ctrl+Numpad_Subtract"

Previously, I rebound it with "Ctrl+Numpad_Subtract, Ctrl+-".

I think both the "Ctrl+Numpad_Subtract" and the "Ctrl+-" can use.

Actually,  only one can use.

(Why did I use the "Ctrl+Numpad_Subtract" directly? Because my notebook has no numeric keyboard)